# Boundary of $A \times B$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. Let $A \subset X$ and $B \subset Y$. Find the boundary of $A \times B$ in term of boundary of $A$ and boundary of $B$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! What do you think should be the correct approach to solving the problem? Where are you getting stuck?

**HINT** If a point is on the boundary of $A$ and in the interior of $B$, is it on the boundary of $A \times B$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this question? Have you made any progress? Are you stuck in any particular place? Please note that questions which simply demand a solution, without any evidence of your work, are often closed here on math.stackexchange. Here's some information about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with particular emphasis on how to [provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960).

Comment: Thanks. Yes it is on the boundary of A×B.

Comment: Similarly a point (x,y)in  X×Y  lies interior of A(x lies in intA)and boundary of B(y lies boundary of B) lies on boundary of A×B. Also a point (x,y) where x lies on boundary of A and y lies on boundary of B .Then it also lies on boundary of A×B. Are there  another points not belonging type of those but in boundary of A×B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denoting by $\partial A$ the boundary of $A$, we have

$$\partial (A \times B) = (\partial A \times \overline{B}) \cup (\overline{A} \times \partial B)\tag{*}$$

and we can expand that if you like, using $\overline{C} = C \cup \partial C$ (for all $C$) as

$$(\partial A \times B)\cup (\partial A \times \partial B) \cup (A \times \partial B) \cup (\partial A \times \partial B)= (\partial A \times B)\cup (\partial A \times \partial B) \cup (A \times \partial B)$$

eliminating the double term, if you want everything in terms of the original sets and their boundaries.

The first identity $(\ast)$ is a straightforward application of the definitions of boundary and the product topology, showing two inclusions. Try to prove it. You can attempt a more algebraic proof if you already know

$$\overline{A \times B}= \overline{A} \times \overline{B}$$

$$\operatorname{int}(A \times B) =  \operatorname{int}(A) \times \operatorname{int}(B)$$

and $$\partial C = \overline{C}\setminus \operatorname{int}(C)$$

applied to $C=A \times B$.